# How to use SSH plugin of Jenkins to connect to EC2

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh

I just want to connect to an Ubuntu EC2 instance, I am using this plugin called https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin

I have added my .pem file in my company's Jenkins's global credentials, after that, I want to login to my Ubuntu Instance, I named that credential ID as myId for example.

If I do it locally, I will open my terminal, type ssh -i localtionOfMyPem ubuntu@10.xx.xxx.xxx

It will connect.

How can I do that on my Jenkins, do I need to config my instance let it know it will be connect by Jenkins first?

Detail steps are expected. Thanks.